# #N/A values are getting treated as zero in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet which has values like `#N/A`. I want them to be treated as Null(np.nan) while loading the excel into `dataframe` but pandas `dataframe` is converting them to 0 value.

Kindly suggest what's wrong with the below code:

```
df=pd.read_excel('sample.xls',header=2,keep_default_na=False,na_values=[''])
```

Thanks !

Comment: What about `df=pd.read_excel('sample.xls',header=2,keep_default_na=False,na_values=['#N/A'])` ?

Comment: Tried and also upgraded the pandas version to 0.19.2.(Document says this is handled be default) Still '#N/A' is getting treated as 0

Comment: I try it and for me it works. It is weird.

Comment: I manually opened that particular value in excel and verified the format. Format of the #N/A is Custom '###,###,###.####;[Red]-###,###,###.####'. I have changed the format to general from custom in Excel. Now it is treating #N/A as NaN. So this is the issue, any clue how do we handle this without changing the format ?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems it is problem.

Comment: Can you please give a try by manually changing the format type in Excel from General to custom and feed the format which I have mentioned, then read the excel using pandas. I believe you ll also face the same issue.